Translate .NET 6 to .NET 4.8 ImportRSAPrivateKey in C# does not exist
I am trying to translate this C# .NET 6.0 code to run on .NET 4.8. I am trying to get a token using a RSA private key pem file. But I didn't succeed.
Please, can someone help me ?
I have a problem with the ImportRSAPrivateKey method. It doesn't exist in .NET 4.8. How can I change this ImportRSAPrivateKey method ?
It is an important method but Is there any other package in .NET 4.8 that can help to change this method?
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace toto.Auth
{
    public class AuthRequestService
    {
        private const string DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK";
        private const string ODC_AUTH_URL = "https://myurl/auth";

        private FileInfo certFile;
        private string partnerId;
        private RSA privateKey;

        private JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase };

        public AuthRequestService(string certFilePath, string partnerId)
        {
            this.certFile = new FileInfo(certFilePath);
            this.privateKey = ReadPKCS8PrivateKey(certFile);
            this.partnerId = partnerId;
        }

        public string GetTokenForRPPS(string rpps)
        {
            var timeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(DATE_PATTERN);

            var body = new AuthRequestDTO(partnerId, rpps, timeStamp);

            string result = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                using (var privateSignature = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    privateSignature.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKey.ExportRSAPrivateKey(), out _);

                    Console.WriteLine("unsigned json:");
                    var unsignedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body, jsonOptions);
                    Console.WriteLine(unsignedJson);

                    var signatureBytes = privateSignature.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unsignedJson), HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
                    string signB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
                    body.Signature = signB64;

                    string signedPayload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body, jsonOptions);

                    Console.WriteLine("signed json:");
                    Console.WriteLine(signedPayload);

                    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ODC_AUTH_URL)
                        {
                            Content = new StringContent(signedPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                        };

                        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest).Result;

                        result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected RSA ReadPKCS8PrivateKey(FileInfo file)
        {
            string key = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
            string privateKeyPEM = key
                .Replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
                .Replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

            byte[] encoded = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyPEM);
            return RSA.Create();
        }
    }
}


You're going the wrong way, translate the 4.8 to 8.0.

I would like to translate to 8.0 but unfortunately I cannot

https://vincentdnl.com/images/drawings/technical-debt/technical-debt.png

.NET Framework 4.8 does not provide notable support for PEM encoded keys. Use BouncyCastle. By the way, ImportRSAPrivateKey() imports a key in PKCS#1 format and not in PKCS#8 format, so the name ReadPKCS8PrivateKey() is misleading.

Do you have an example using BouncyCastle ?

You can find various examples on SO e.g. here, first code snippet. After the key has been imported, you can either use the BouncyCastle classes for signing (as in the example) or you convert the Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters using DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters() to System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters, import them (e.g. into an RSACryptoServiceProvider) and use the built-in C# classes.
